# Cannot convert letters to numbers and reverse

Tags: java, performance

I'm trying to write a function that allows me to convert inputted letters to numbers and vice versa, so far I keep getting compiling errors. I want to keep this small and efficient without having to do an extensive if, else if statement.

This is my code so far:

```
public class CaesarCipher {

    /*
     * create function that converts a letter to a number
     * ex. a -> 0, b -> 1, etc...
     */
    static char letterToNumber (char firstLetter){
        if (firstLetter < 'a' || firstLetter > 'z') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only lower-case ASCII letters are valid");
    }
    return (char) (firstLetter - 'a');
    }

    /*
     * function to allow a user input a number and converts to a letter
     * 0->a and 1->b, etc...
     */
    static int numberToLetter (int firstNumer){
        if (firstNumber < '0' || firstNumber > '25'){   
        }
        return firstNumber;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char a = 0;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println (letterToNumber (a)); //suppose to compile to convert a -> the number 0
        System.out.println(numberToLetter (1)); //compile to convert 1 -> the letter b
    }

}
```

Comment: In the future, if you're asking about problems with compiler errors, then ***show*** the errors with your question. Makes sense, no? Also please have a look at [help] as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your future questions and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm new to all of this. java programming and using this site for resource help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 'a' + in your return statement in numberToLetter

```
return 'a' + firstNumber;
```

Comment: so I made the corrections and my returns when I input a and 1 I get the following results:

?
97

I am suppose to get the results of: 
0
a